# Recursive RESTAPI Query

Tags: javascript, rest, odata

For some background, I have a number of enterprise systems management products that run a REST API called Redfish. I can visit the root folder on one such device by going here:

https://ip.of.device/redfish/v1

If I browse the raw JSON from a GET request, the output includes JSON data that look like this. I'm truncating this due to how long it is, so perhaps some JSON syntax errors here.

```
{
    Description: "Data",
    AccountService: {
    @odata.id: "/redfish/v1/AccountService"
    },
    CertificateService: {
    @odata.id: "/redfish/v1/CertificateService"
    }
}
```

Perhaps in my searching I'm using the wrong terminology, but each of those @odata.id items is basically a 'folder' I can navigate into. Each folder has additional data values, but still more folders. I can capture contents of folders I know about via javascript and parse the JSON simple enough, but there are hundreds of folders here, some multiple layers deep and from one device to the next, sometimes the folders are different.

Due to the size and dynamic nature of this data, is there a way to either recursively query this from an API itself or recursively 'scrape' an API's @odata.id 'folder' structure like this using Javascript? I'm tempted to write a bunch of nested queries in foreach loops, but there's surely a better way to accomplish this.

My eventual goal is to perform this from nodejs, parse the data, then present the data in a web form for a user to select what fields to keep, which we'll store for faster lookups in a mongodb database along with the path to the original data for more targeted api queries later.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Redfish spec says you can query directly for the services: https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0266_1.12.0.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I did try that, but it doesn't seem to work here. This path should theoretically get everything within this path and all @odata.id links, but it's returning query parameter $expand is invalid. This path is one i used. Will keep experimenting though.
/redfish/v1/Chassis/System.Embedded.1?$expand=~